# How to debug Android application in phone sleep mode without USB connection

Tags: android, debugging

That's tricky one, I guess. Phone behaves differently when connected with USB (for debugging) and when unplugged. Difference is in the sleep mode - with USB connection phone seems to be more active and responsive, without - less. For example, I have an alarm to wake up the phone and adjust volume. While connected - works perfectly fine in sleep (adjusts volume on every alarm trigger, every 10 seconds). While not connected - works rarely (adjusts volume only on random alarm trigger, let's say between 20 and 50 seconds).

How could I debug the phone while unplugged? How could I force the phone to behave exactly the same with USB connection and without? Partial wake lock (the one without screen on) doesn't help. This is strange and it makes the developing really painful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was quite easy, but the easy answers always come last: I installed aLogcat from the market and it seems to work just fine! Great app to see the logs without the computer, straight on the phone.

Answer (score 3):

You can access adb over a network connection:

> When debugging applications that use USB accessory or host features,
>   you most likely will have USB hardware connected to your
>   Android-powered device. This will prevent you from having an adb
>   connection to the Android-powered device via USB. You can still access
>   adb over a network connection. To enable adb over a network
>   connection:

1. Connect the Android-powered device via USB to your computer.
2. From your SDK platform-tools/ directory, enter adb tcpip 5555 at the command prompt.
3. Enter adb connect :5555 You should now be connected to the Android- powered device and can issue the usual adb commands like adb logcat.
4. To set your device to listen on USB, enter adb usb.

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/index.html

Comment: Yes, this works, but it does keep phone in this less-sleep state. My alarms and volume adjustments are exactly every 10s while debugging over WiFi. When I disconnect the debugger - it starts being random again... Ubeliveable, but that's the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can start a logcat session in some service, and save it to file, after you're done, get the log from the device.

Comment: Right, but that's not really convenient, is it?

Comment: Depends on your needs, I suggested it since we use it in a continuous integration system to retrieve logs of our test suites (around a hundred every day)

Answer (score 0):

You can use apphance: http://www.apphance.com/ - this is a new service which my company developed. It allows to see logs of  android application fully remotely, it also records conditions of the device (like USB/connected/disconnected). You can see logs of the application in a web panel. It's extremely useful for remotely debugging if you are not in a possesion of particular phone, but it covers your case pretty well.

You can sign-up for beta access - the service is in beta phase, it will soon be opened for regular use.