# android, debug not connected to PC, no wifi?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

I need to set breakpoints in my program. However I can't be connected to PC for debugging, only for launching the app. I have no wifi capability yet. Can I put something on the tablet that will work? i have catlog but that is not what I nee on it's own. I tried to run the program in debug mode with hit count = 10 but it did not work. The program kept executing.

Comment: 1. What IDE are you using? And, 2. Are you really really sure that the code breakpointed is beign executed?

Comment: Sorry for being confused. But, if you can launch the app, why can't you debug? These are some of the better apps for debugging when not connect via USB: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&feature=search_result, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bohlool.net.wifiadb&feature=search_result, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ryosoftware.adbw&feature=search_result. But you will still need WiFi enabled for that.

Comment: I am using eclipse. I am not sure the breakpoint is working correctly no, no way to test it. I can launch the app but not debug it as after I launch it I must disconnect it and connect it to a serial device to send/receive data. I must test this.

Comment: I guess I cant do it until my wifi card arrives.

Comment: Have you got USB debugging turned on your phone, debug enabled set to true in the manifest file, selected the app in the developer options and also set the wait for debugger option to true in the developer options on your device

Comment: I have debug turned on on phone, have it set in developer options and selecting run in debug mode should mean taht I don't have to set it up in the manifest. I don't see any 'wait for debugger' option however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is: can't do it, need wifi or to be connected to pc

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to adb over a network connection. See:

[How to debug Android application in phone sleep mode without USB connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713050/how-to-debug-android-application-in-phone-sleep-mode-without-usb-connection)

Android has an option for debugging via a network connection so that you can use your usb port for other hardware.

> When debugging applications that use USB accessory or host features,
>   you most likely will have USB hardware connected to your
>   Android-powered device. This will prevent you from having an adb
>   connection to the Android-powered device via USB. You can still access
>   adb over a network connection.

Comment: Yeah i know, I mentioned I don't have wifi yet, unfortunately. guess I'll just have to wait for the wifi card to arrive.