# how to save log cat all message during testing of application

Tags: android, android-testing

My application is running fine but when it went in testing,it have some issue somewhere it got crashed and some issue also happens my question is how can i get all logs of my application in testing phase from device when device is not connection to computer because tester not use eclipse.
please help me to resolve this. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713050/how-to-debug-android-application-in-phone-sleep-mode-without-usb-connection

Comment: yup but tester is not using eclipse dude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want log. You can use the code below:

```
  logcatProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds);  
                mReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(logcatProc.getInputStream()), 1024);  
                String line = null;  
                while ((line = mReader.readLine()) != null) {  
                    if (line.length() == 0) {  
                        continue;  
                    }  
                    if (out != null && line.contains(mPID)) {  
                        out.write((simpleDateFormat2.format(new Date()) + "  " + line + "\n").getBytes());  
                    }  
                }
```

cmds = "logcat *:e *:i | grep \"(" + mPID + ")\"";

you can use your own grep format.

Tips: The logcat will be flushed off in a while

so you should put above code in a thread

Answer (score 3):

You should use a crash report library like [BugSense](https://www.bugsense.com/) or [Accra](https://github.com/ACRA/acra).

This kind of libs mimics the Android market feature of released apps, but during testing phase : you can get complete crash reports, with stack traces and other data (first time/last time of bug occurence, device model, etc.)

Comment: thanks for reply can u give me any reference or example of this

Answer (score 1):

You should try [android-logging-log4j](https://code.google.com/p/android-logging-log4j/).

By the help of this Api you can record all the crash log in form of **Text, Xml format** and will be stored in the path you will provide like `Phone memory or SD card`.

So even if device is in Offline mode all the crash entry will be recorded over there. So you can get from that device and go through it for debugging.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: With that perspective in mind, logback for Android maybe more modern : https://github.com/tony19/logback-android

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this code to get your own project logs.

```
public  class  LogcatFileManager {

    private  static  LogcatFileManager INSTANCE = null ;  
    private  static  String PATH_LOGCAT;  
    private  LogDumper mLogDumper = null ;  
    private  int  MPID;

    private  SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat1 = new  SimpleDateFormat ( "yyyyMMdd" );
    private  SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat2 = new  SimpleDateFormat ( "yyyy-MM-dd HH: mm: SS" );

    public  static  LogcatFileManager getInstance () {  
        if  (INSTANCE == null ) {  
            INSTANCE = new  LogcatFileManager ();  
        }  
        return  INSTANCE;  
    }

    private  LogcatFileManager () {  
        MPID = android.os.Process.myPid ();  
    }

    private  void  setFolderPath (String folderPath) {

        File folder = new  File (folderPath);
        if  (! folder.exists ()) {
            folder.mkdirs ();
        }

        if  (! folder.isDirectory ())
            throw  new  IllegalArgumentException ( "The folder path is Not a logcat Directory:"  + folderPath);

        PATH_LOGCAT = folderPath.endsWith("/") ? folderPath : folderPath + "/";

    }

    public  void  start (String saveDirectoy) {

        setFolderPath (saveDirectoy);

        if  (mLogDumper == null )  
            mLogDumper = new LogDumper (String.valueOf (MPID), PATH_LOGCAT);  
        mLogDumper.start ();  
    } 

    public  void  stop () {  
        if  (mLogDumper!=null ) {
            mLogDumper.stopLogs();
            mLogDumper = null ;
        }  
    }

    public  class  LogDumper extends  Thread {  

        private  Process logcatProc;  
        private  BufferedReader MReader = null ;  
        private  boolean  mRunning = true ;  
        String cmds = null ;  
        private  String MPID;  
        private  FileOutputStream out = null ;  

        public  LogDumper (String pid, String dir) { 

            MPID = pid;

            try  {  
                out = new  FileOutputStream (new File(dir, "logcat-"  + simpleDateFormat1.format (new Date ()) +".log"),true);
            } catch  (FileNotFoundException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace ();  
            }  
            cmds = "logcat *:e *:i | grep \"(" + MPID + ")\"";  
        }

        public  void  stopLogs () {  
            mRunning = false ;  
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try  {  
                logcatProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds);  
                MReader = new  BufferedReader ( new  InputStreamReader (logcatProc.getInputStream ()), 1024 );  
                String line = null ;  
                while  (mRunning && (line=MReader.readLine())!=null ) {  
                    if  (! mRunning) {  
                        break ;  
                    }  
                    if  (line.length () == 0 ) {  
                        continue ;  
                    }  
                    if  (out!=null  && line.contains (MPID)) {  
                        out.write ((simpleDateFormat2.format(new Date())+""+line+"\n").getBytes());  
                    }  
                }  

            } catch  (IOException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace ();  
            } finally  {  
                if  (logcatProc!=null ) {  
                    logcatProc.destroy();  
                    logcatProc = null ;  
                }
                if  (MReader!=null) {
                    try  {  
                        MReader.close ();  
                        MReader = null ;  
                    } catch  (IOException e) {  
                        e.printStackTrace ();  
                    } 
                }
                if (out!=null) {  
                    try {  
                        out.close ();  
                    } catch  (IOException e) {  
                        e.printStackTrace ();  
                    }  
                    out = null ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

crashlytics is something you need: http://try.crashlytics.com/
You will be informed about errors, version of app that crashed etc...